# Difference between Multivariate and Multidimensional data - Data Mining

Tags: data-mining

I was reading "Data Classes" in Data Mining Foundations and came across-
Multivariate and Multidimensional data.

I am confused between the two. In my understanding, if each observation within a dataset has say 3 variables such as- name, age and gender then this is an example of 'Multivariate' data.

What can be thought of as an example for 'Multidimensional' data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In statistics, dimensions are usually referred to as "variates" or "variables".

So it is the same thing, just a MLAs common in a different domain.

Comment: This is an old post, but what is MLA? I tried Googling the term, but the results just show MLA the citation format which I don't think is the case here.